# Jhipster "From address must not be null" exception while registering

Tags: jhipster

I have the same issue as the bug discribed in this link : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/467

In fact, I have this warning "service.MailService - E-mail could not be sent to user 'xxx@gmail.com', exception is: From address must not be null"

But in my application.yml I specified the from variable and it is equal to my user email.

Any idea why i get this error ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. After some debugging I found the solution. In the service MailService.java the 'From' address is retreived by this code:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.from = env.getProperty("spring.mail.from");
}
```

However, the property "spring.mail.from" doesn't exist in application.yml. It should be "mail.from". So without the "spring" prefix.

Changing this to this code solved the problem for me:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.from = env.getProperty("mail.from");
}
```

Regards,
Rogier

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed as said by @Rogier, the issue is du to mail.form.
An issue has been raisen in Github at the following link : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1462